# Dialogflow RPC Python Dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dialogflow-es

I am using `dialogflow` pip package to communicate with my agent in dialogflow. I am able to get it to work. But there is no method to convert what object I have to a python dictionary. for example, the `google.cloud.dialogflow_v2.types.DetectIntentResponse` object has no method to convert to a python `dict`. Am I missing something or the support itself isn't there? And if it is the second one, why so?

Comment: Isn't the `DetectIntentResponse` object already a dictionary? From https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/DetectIntentResponse it looks like you access the the returned parameters using dictionary lookups

Comment: @ScottMcC You are looking at REST reference. Please see RPC reference.